# Having issues with Expo on develop app but not on the same app in local

Tags: react-native, expo

My team and I are developing a Expo + React Native app. When we push the app to publish on expo, we are having some issues on the app that, on local testing isnt happening.

For example, I have 2 photos from the same page and the results are:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FLGR.png)

On this image, we can see a partial image from a view where you can see the number of pets and some propeties that you have register.

As you can see, there are 3 dogs with the same properties but, on [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdttD.jpg) you can see that, on the same page, we only see 3 dogs, and all of them arent the same.

The first image are from the published expo app and the second is from local, but the same app.

Thank so much!

Comment: Welcome @Sergio Garrido Domínguez on StackOverflow, It would be really helpful if you attached your code snippet with your question. It will help others to rectify the issue quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but we could face off this error on a new deploy! We didnt know what could happened to the first, but the last one was ok!